# Folium || Highlight specific countries based on some data?

Tags: python, maps, folium

**Problem:** I would like to highlight specific countries based on some data I have. As an example, I have a list of shows and countries where they are licensed. I would like to highlight those countries when a show is selected or searched *selecting and searching comes later in the program right now I just want to be able to highlight specific countries.

I have been following the Folium Quickstart page here https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html ,specifically the GeoJSON and TopoJSON. This is the code I have right now and it highlights every country on the map.

```
#Loads show data into panda dataframe
show_data = pd.read_csv('input files/Show Licensing.csv')
show_data['Contract Expiration'] = pd.to_datetime(show_data['Contract Expiration'])
#Loads country poloygon and names
country_geo=(open("input files/countries.geojson", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")).read()
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[40.738, -73.98],
                        tiles="CartoDB positron",
                        zoom_start=5)
folium.GeoJson(country_geo).add_to(folium_map)
folium_map.save("my_map.html")
```

**Expected Results:** For right now I would like to highlight all countries found in my csv file. End goal is to be able to search a show and highlight countries where the show is licensed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote which answered my question:

```
for country in countriesAndContinents_json['features']:
        if country['properties']['Name'].lower() == h_country.lower():
            if highlightFlag == 'License A':
                return folium.GeoJson(
                                country,
                                name=(showTitle + ' License A ' + h_country),
                                style_function=styleLicenseA_function,
                                highlight_function=highlightLicenseA_function
                                )
```

'country', which is used as the geo_data for folium.GeoJson, is the geojson response for a specific country. So when a search for a country is found in the countries.geojson data it will return the geojson response for that specific country, including the geometry needed to highlight it.